# getJSON gives statut 200 but no value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I've found a dozen of questions about this problem, but none of the solutions seem to help me.

I've got a piece of PHP code that creates an JSON object, basicly my page looks like this:

```
<?php
    $supps = ...; /* mysqli class that gets the values */
    header("Content-type: text/javascript");
    echo json_encode( $supps );
?>
```

When going to the page `feed.php?load&menu_id=2` it shows the object:

```
[{"id":32,"name":"Test 4","weight":15},{"id":33,"name":"Test 5","weight":25},{"id":34,"name":"Test 6","weight":35}]
```

Running this through the [JSONlint validator](http://jsonlint.com/) gives me this (valid!) result

```
[
    {
        "id": 32,
        "name": "Test 4",
        "weight": 15
    },
    {
        "id": 33,
        "name": "Test 5",
        "weight": 25
    },
    {
        "id": 34,
        "name": "Test 6",
        "weight": 35
    }
]
```

Now I'm trying to load this data with a JQuery function (based on a selected value from a form). I've tried multiple pieces of code:

```
/* Try 1 */
var menuID = $('[name=menu]:checked').val();
$.getJSON("feed.php?load&amp;menu_id="+menuID, function(json) {
    console.log(json);
});

/* Try 2 */
var menuID = $('[name=menu]:checked').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "feed.php?load&amp;menu_id"+menuID,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(json){
          console.log(json);
    }
})

/* Try 3 */
var menuID = $('[name=menu]:checked').val();
$.getJSON("feed.php?load&amp;menu_id="+menuID, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}).done(function(xhr) {
    console.log(xhr)
});

/* Try 4 */
var menuID = $('[name=menu]:checked').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "feed.php?load&amp;menu_id="+menuID,
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Every try gives me the same result in the console:

```
GET http://.../feed.php?load&amp;menu_id=1 200 OK 51ms
```

But no object in the console.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What happens when you alert instead of console.log. Just curious.

Comment: @ODelibalta, tried it on try 1 and 4, nothing happens (no alert is shown).

Comment: Can you check the network tab of the debugger and check the response body. If a response exists, then it's a parsing issue. If there's no response, then it's a server-side issue.

Comment: Did you try changing `"feed.php?load&amp;menu_id="+menuID,` by `"feed.php?load&menu_id="+menuID,`

Comment: Do you echo the json or return it from your php function ? Echo is the right way to go. In addition, instead of `console.log(data)` just do `console.log('randomString')` just to see that your code gets there at all .

Comment: try using `&` instead of `&amp;` in url the same way you do opening it in browser

Comment: Also, the correct mimetype for json is `application/json`

Comment: @Mindastic charlietfl, thank you, that was the problem. At JosephtheDreamer: thanks, will change that. At all: thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL contains an encoded ampersand:

> feed.php?load&amp;menu_id="+menuID

`&amp;` is not decoded when used in a URL. Your query string is broken.

Comment: I oversaw that one... thank you, that solves my problem!